# Error while updating property 'numberOfLines' in shadow node of type: RCTText

Tags: react-native, expo

Using `expo sdk-38`

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Expo encountered a fatal error: Error while updating property 'numberOfLines' in shadow node of type: RCTText
       at host.exp.exponent.experience.BaseExperienceActivity$2.run(BaseExperienceActivity.java:206)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

What could be the reason for this and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in your codebase for any `<Text>` elements using `numberOfLines` - are any of them setting this to something that is not a number? Are any libraries you're pulling in doing that?

There's not enough information to be more specific here, and I suspect you won't be able to get more detailed logs too. If you can reliably reproduce it, try removing some components until it works to hone in the area that's breaking.

Comment: I don't have other than number. Its like

```<Text  style={[styles.connectText, { color: Colors.darker }]} numberOfLines={1}> Pending...</Text>```

Yeah I am using the ```react-native-read-more-text```

```<ReadMore numberOfLines={5} renderTruncatedFooter={this.renderViewMore} renderRevealedFooter={this.renderViewLess}><Text style={Styles.bodyText}>Hello</Text</ReadMore>```

Comment: That package looks safe - the issue is probably somewhere else. Can you reproduce the issue reliably - or are you seeing it in your production crash logs?